# related to onCreateOptionMenu on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am very much new in android development. trying to make a dictionary application where a button in main activity suppose to open next activity.

to do that I am following a tutorial.
there is a method like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

after writing this on an error notification come beside eclipse that

*"The method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` of type `new View.OnClickListener(){}` must override or implement a supertype method"*

I do not understand how to correct my program.

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

the above are already `imported class` but still the error is there.
what I have to import or what I have to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should inherit form some kind of Activity either one from the support package
E.g. android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: it is inherited from a supported package

Comment: It is included in at least the latest version of the support pack. But you any type of Activity would do. E.g. the android.app.Activity. But I think you get android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity by default if you create a new app in eclipse with the latest android tools